# How can i put my application button in iphone notification center?

Tags: ios, notifications

I want to put a Button in notification bar like Twitter button. How can i do this. Is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible sorry.

Comment: Ok, so can i make my own notification type and design? (buttons in a layout. )